# Java overloading for ArrayList data types

Tags: java, overloading

Why I can not have both of this two methods in same class?

```
public double foo(ArrayList<Integer>  x);
public double foo(ArrayList<Double>  d);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241514/overloading-java-function-with-list-parameter

Answer (score 4):

When Java implemented generics, to make the bytecode backwards compatible, they came up with *type erasure*.  That means that at runtime, the generic information is gone.  So the signatures are really:

```
public double foo(ArrayList  x);
public double foo(ArrayList  d);
```

and you have two methods with the same signature.

The solution here would be not to overload the method name; name the two methods different names.

Here's the [Java Generics Tutorial Page on type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: There are other solutions. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2241584/691859 But, thanks for the clarification on type erasure.

Comment: @rgettman absolutely nothing personal here, it's just that google returned this as the very first result on my query... if you take this single method `public double foo(ArrayList<Double> d) {
        return 12D;
    }`, compile it and de-compile it using `javap`, it will have the proper generic information `public double foo(java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Double>);`... so when you compile, the generic information is there. the problem would happen if this would have been allowed at the *call-site*, because the call-site generics would have been erased

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that both methods have the same method signature. To overload methods they must have the same name and return type but different method signature, in you case both method accepts a array list.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you try to change it to:

```
public double fooInteger(ArrayList<Integer>  x);
public double fooDouble(ArrayList<Double>  d);
```

I had a similar problem with my applet until I changed the name of the second array.

Comment: This entirely defeats the purpose of overloading.

Comment: If OP is trying to overload a method, i.e. use a method name more than once, then the solution is obviously not to give up and use a new method name.